# How do I load an embedded resource using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, maven

I'm developing a desktop Swing app using Kotlin.  Here is a screenshot of my app's source folder structure.  I'm using Maven to build the project.

[image: screenshot of source folder structure]

I'm trying to set the icon for a button using the following lone of code.

```
btnNewGame.icon = ImageIcon(javaClass.getResource("/com/gmail/fishnet37222/fndice/New24.gif"))
```

However, when I try to run the app, I get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:232)
    at com.gmail.fishnet37222.fndice.MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.kt:76)
    at com.gmail.fishnet37222.fndice.MainWindowKt.main$lambda$0(MainWindow.kt:33)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Typically you should use `getResourceAsStream("/.../")` and check if `ImageIcon` can handle an inputstream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException you're encountering typically occurs when the getResource method returns null. This can happen if the resource is not found at the specified path.

Verify Resource Path. If your resource is in the same package as your class, you might not need the leading slash /:

```
val iconURL = YourClassName::class.java.getResource("New24.gif")
```